# QGIS SAGA Kriging tools not working with my data

Tags: qgis, kriging

I've been trying to create surfaces using Kriging from the geochemical sample data points I have, using SAGA ordinary kriging. But the tool doesn’t work.

[image: the error message I get]

[image: processing tab in the message log]

[image: Message log]

Most of my data points have 50m*100m spacing. So I gave cell size 20.

Interesting thing is that I accidently ran the tool and got a prediction surface and prediction error using "fid" as the attribute value.

but when I select my true attribute values( element concentration in ppm ; field type decimal) the tool won't run!
Also I'm not confident about my choice of maximum distance (200) and lag classes(100) .

What am I doing wrong?